# Change layout order when dragging dynamically in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

There are top `Constraintlayout` and bottom `HorizontalScrollView` respectively in the root `Constraintlayout` and all of layouts item for a `RecyclerView`. Dragging all of the layouts when the long press with holder of top layout, but dragging to top direction isn't suitable for user experience, so how can be placed the bottom layout to over of top layout during the dragging if the layouts is first half of the screen or the exact opposite as follow:

[image]

Comment: It's not a simple thing to explain in the SO answer. This requires a more complex implementation. You need to understand how custom views work and basically mimic the `BottomSheet` behavior (if that's what you're copying), and make it suited for your needs. This will require custom calculations of the drag position and manually repositioning views. Personally, I don't see an easy way to do it using the built-in Android tools.

Comment: I would need some code samples for better understanding what is given. My first guess is to register a custom OnTouchListener to get the current position and subtract it from the screensize and then switch the viewholders constraints if a 
threshold is exceeded. Probably do this check asynchronous for Ux